# link not working on my drop down menu

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, menu

I have a drop down menu that goes like that : MENU > portfolio/services/about/contact.But my links are not working. here's the jquery. At first my links wer working but the page was scrolling to the top automaticly when clicking on "menu" and to prevent that someone told me to add the code  " e.preventDefault();" that corrected the scrolling top isssue but now links arent working. Thanks for the help!

```
$(function () {
    $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();});
    $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
    $('.clicker').removeClass('active');}
    });
    }); 

    $('.click-nav > ul').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: `preventDefault` prevents the browser from following the link. 

So make sure your `preventDefault` is only applied to `menu`.

Comment: Perfect it works thanks :) !!